# Setting UITabBarItem isEnabled to false hides the icon not grays it out

Tags: ios, swift

Setting UITabBarItem used to gray out the icon of the TabBar, I tried it today and the icon is completely hidden. 
I use the following lines to disable it

```
   //disable Orders Tab
    if  let arrayOfTabBarItems = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items as AnyObject as? NSArray, let tabBarItem = arrayOfTabBarItems[1] as? UITabBarItem {

        tabBarItem.isEnabled = false
    }
```

and this is the result

[image]

this is how it looks before

[image]

Comment: are you setting it in storyboard ?

Comment: @jawadAli the same result when i set it in storyboard

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this by creating the TabBarController by code.
In TabbarController, you can create some conditional and then set ViewController to Tabbar manually.

```
    switch some-condition {
       case .condition : 
           viewControllers = [vc1,vc2]
       case .otherOne :
           viewControllers = [vc1,vc2,vc3,vc4,vc4] 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you but i want the grayed out icons, i don't want to surprise the user about the other icons when he logs in.

Comment: In that case, you can create a fake tabbar and set your tabbar hidden. I dont think that TabbarViewController support multiple color.

Comment: It is not multiple colors, setting isEnable = false used to gray out the icon, this is just happened to me lately maybe because i updated the Xcode

Answer (score 0):

I was working with Xcode 11.2 beta version, when i updated to Xcode 11.5 stable version the problem solved without any modification.

[image]